# where is ipt_ECH.h file in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

In the linux kernel 3.16.56, there is a source code including `linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h` ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16.56/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ECN.c#L20 )

But there is no ipt_ECN.h in that location. Then, where is ipt_ECN.h?
How the kernel can be compiled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given header exists under `include/uapi`: [include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16.56/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h).

Directory `include/uapi` contains header files common both for kernel code and for user programs/libraries. Normally, there are only types definitions, without functions.